# Changing JBoss BRMS (Drools) to use Oracle 11g: Unable to build package

Tags: jboss, oracle11g, drools, guvnor

I am using Guvnor (JBoss BRMS) to manage my drools rule engine which is deployed within JBoss EAP 5.3. I've altered Guvnor to use an Oracle 11g instance for it's RDBMS. I used Guvnor to generate a new repository.xml and placed this into 'bin' folder of the JBoss directory. Guvnor and Drools ran up fine and seemed happy to connect to the Oracle 11g instance.

I then proceeded to create a package and add a new rule. The rule I added is below:

```
dialect "mvel"

rule "TimeToClearRule"
when
    #conditions
then
    #actions
end
```

I validated this rule and then rebuilt the package. Everything worked fine!

However, I then proceeded to add a function above the rule, with the intention of using this in the rule. The rule altered to what is below:

```
dialect "mvel"

function double logNormalPdf(double mu, double sigma, double timeT) {
    return 0.0;
}

rule "TimeToClearRule"
when
    #conditions
then
    #actions
end
```

I validated this rule and rebuilt the package. However, an error was then thrown up. It was unable to 'save the item'. In my JBoss logs, the following error was shown (Note: not the complete stacktrace, only added what I believe to be the root cause)

```
 17:59:51,815 ERROR [BundleWriter] Error while storing blob. id=9d26c61c-4dde-4009-a518-1f226431aa80/{http://www.jboss.org/drools-repository/1.0}compiledPackage idx=0 size=4353
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to insert index for string: compiledPackage
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.NGKDbNameIndex.insertString(NGKDbNameIndex.java:66)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.DbNameIndex.stringToIndex(DbNameIndex.java:95)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.BundleDbPersistenceManager$DbBlobStore.createId(BundleDbPersistenceManager.java:1334)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DROOLS"."PM_WS_DEFAULT_NAMES"."ID")

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
```

When Drools/Guvnor is using the default DBMS solution the rule validates and builds fine. It's since moving the DBMS to Oracle 11g that the rule can no longer be validated and the package built.

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. Any help offered would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE** Right, I found what I believe is the problem. There was something I missed in the example above which I have found to be the cause of the error. I am using the 'Math' functions (java.lang.Math) and this seems to cause the error shown above. The rule I am creating is as follows:

```
import java.lang.Math

dialect "mvel"

function double logNormalPdf(double mu, double sigma, double timeT) {
    return Math.log(2);
}

rule "TimeToClearRule"
when
    #conditions
then
    #actions
end
```

Can drools/guvnor handle the Math functions? If not, how do I go about using this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried exporting the repository.xml and importing it instead of replacing the original repository.xml in the bin folder?

Comment: Hi jBug, I can't find the option to import a repository, there is only export.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a problem with your db configuration, guvnor / jackrabbit might not be able to create all the necessary tables in the oracle repository. try to do a fresh db connection to a new oracle schema.

Comment: Hi alikox, I'll give this a whirl and see how if it fixes the problem.

Comment: One thing, I did create a new schema and it appears to have created all the tables. The table referenced in the exception is present, it's just trying to insert null into it for some reason.

Comment: I tried what you suggested alikox and that didn't work. I'm tempted to go back to using the default JackRabbit solution provided by Guvnor out of the box

Comment: @ScreamingMage Sorry to hear that. The reason I suggested this possibility was, I had encountered a similar error when using Oracle 10g repository and Guvnor could not create all of its tables due to a Locale difference.